# AHK_L Com Excel TextToColumns

Tags: excel, com, autohotkey

I need some help getting my script to work with AHK_L COM Excel on TextToColumns.  I've looked around but can't seem to locate enough examples to get me going.  When I have run my VBA macro this is what I end up with:

```
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Examples I have found look like my code should be:
`xl.Selection.TextToColumns([color=#FF0000]xl.range("D1")[/color],1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,":")`

But nothing happens to my column that's selected.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xl.Selection.TextToColumns(xl.range("D1"),1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,":")
```

Try it with out the color tags

Comment: Oh Thanks blackholyman for some reason I didn't get a notification that this was answered.  I ended up at the same result awhile back and it worked. My apologies for not responding sooner.